# Best way to move a column in pandas dataframe to last column in large dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with more than 100 columns.
For example in the following df:

```
df['A','B','C','D','E','date','G','H','F','I']
```

How can I move date to be the last column? assuming the dataframe is large and i cant write all the column names manually.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can try this:

```
new_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col != 'date'] + ['date']
df = df[new_cols]
```

Test data:

```
cols = ['A','B','C','D','E','date','G','H','F','I']
df = pd.DataFrame([np.arange(len(cols))],
                  columns=cols)

print(df)
#    A  B  C  D  E  date  G  H  F  I
# 0  0  1  2  3  4     5  6  7  8  9
```

Output of the code:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  G  H  F  I  date
0  0  1  2  3  4  6  7  8  9     5
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.pop` and `pandas.concat`:

```
print(df)
   col1  col2  col3
0     1    11   111
1     2    22   222
2     3    33   333

s = df.pop('col1')
new_df = pd.concat([df, s], 1)
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
   col2  col3  col1
0    11   111     1
1    22   222     2
2    33   333     3
```

Answer (score 1):

This way :

```
df_new=df.loc[:,df.columns!='date']
df_new['date']=df['date']
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple reindexing should do the job:

```
original = df.columns
new_cols = original.delete(original.get_loc('date'))
df.reindex(columns=new_cols)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reindex` and `union`:

```
df.reindex(df.columns[df.columns != 'date'].union(['date']), axis=1)
```

Let's only work with the index headers and not the complete dataframe.

Then, use reindex to reorder the columns.

Output using @QuangHoang setup:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  date
0  0  1  2  3  4  8  6  7  9     5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use movecolumn package in Python to move columns:

```
pip install movecolumn
```

Then you can write your code as:

```
import movecolumn as mc
mc.MoveToLast(df,'date')
```

Hope that helps.

P.S : The package can be found here. https://pypi.org/project/movecolumn/